# How to fix 'Request contains an invalid argument' error when scheduling queries in BigQuery UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm setting up a scheduled query in the new **BigQuery UI** as the project owner and have enabled the data transfer API. The query itself is a very simple `SELECT * FROM table` query written in standard SQL. The datasets I'm using are in the same region.

No matter how I set up the schedule options (start now, schedule start time, daily, weekly, etc.) or the destination dataset/table, I always get the same error:

> "Error updating scheduled query: Request contains an invalid argument."

I have no idea which argument is invalid, it gives no more detail than that.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

By trying to schedule the query in the classic BigQuery UI, it shows a more descriptive error which illustrates the issue:

> Error in creating a new transfer: BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location northamerica-northeast1.

The data must be stored in either the US or the EU at this time, it seems.